# Claim that the class of context-free languages is closed under $f$

Tags: computer-science, computational-mathematics

Given an alphabet $\Sigma$, consider the operation $f : \Sigma^* → \Sigma^*$, defined as
$$
f(w) = w_n \circ w_{n−1} \circ w_{n−2} \circ \cdots \circ w_1,
$$
where $w = w_1 \circ w_2 \circ w_3 \circ \cdots \circ w_n$. $f$ is extended to apply to a given language $L$ as follows:
$$
f(L) = \{f(w) \mid w \in L\}.
$$

Prove or disprove the claim that the class of context-free languages is closed under $f$.

Comment: Don't just post a homework problem with none of your own efforts. What are you having trouble with? Do you understand the question? Have you considered any examples?